# Proof of the general case for Fermat's little theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

I have proved Fermat's little theorem (F.L.T) that is "If $p$ be a prime, then $x^p=x\bmod p$ " by induction on x for $x \in \mathbb Z$ and $x \ge 0$. I want to prove the general case that is for $x \lt 0$.

**Here is my attempt**

Proof: Let $y =-x$. Since y is positive, thus by F.L.T we have $y^p= y \bmod p$. So $(-x)^p=-x \bmod p$. If $p \gt 2$, then $x^p=x \bmod p$ and we are done. If $p = 2$, then $x^2 =-x \bmod p$.

Here I stuck how can I proceed further to reach at $x^p = x \bmod p$ for $p=2$? Thank you.

Comment: If $p=2$ then $x\equiv 0 \text{ or } 1\bmod 2$ so checking both cases $x\equiv -x \bmod 2$ and similarly $x^2\equiv x \bmod 2$

Answer (score 0):

I'm just a 13 year old who loves maths so my answer might be wrong, but, following your work and to answer your request, notice that Fermat's little theorem indicates that $p\not|a$. Since $p=2$, $a\equiv 1 \mod [2]$
Now, the rest is quite obvious, notice that, $-1\mod[2]$ and $1\mod[2]$ are the same, since 2-1 is 1, and 2+1=3, $3\equiv 1\mod[2]$ , thus, we have proved what you sought for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).